# Elastic Search Group by field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following data in my index.

```
{
"id":1,
"car_name" : "ABC-101"
},
{
"id":2,
"car_name" : "DEF-102"
},
{
"id":3,
"car_name" : "ABC-103"
}
```

Mapping of my index is

```
{
  "car": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "car_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Whey i run the following query

```
 localhost:9200/car/_doc/_search?pretty
```

With following request body

```
{
"size" : 0,
"aggs" : {
    "genres" : {
        "terms" : { 
            "field" : "car_name"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get the following response

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "ABC",
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "DEF",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "101",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "102",
      "doc_count": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "103",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
]
```

Why it is not bring the actual keys which are ABC-101 and DEF-102 why ABC and 101 are treated as separated keys.

Comment: Can you also show your index mapping please?

Comment: Should be a token issue. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html , like generate_word_parts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, string fields are `analyzed` in elasticsearch. It means that
**"ABC-101"** is indexed as 2 terms **"ABC"** and **"101"**. Your
query is also **analyzed**, and it's also converted into 2 terms "ABC" and "101"
no matter which special characters are in between them.

That's why they are matching all the strings separated by `-` like **ABC, 101, DEF, 102** and so on.

e.g

```
  {
    "car": {
      "car_name": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }  
  }
```

If you want to search this field exactly as it is, you should re-index it as `"index":"not_analyzed"`

You can make it work with `keyword` on car_name field to match exactly

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs" : {
      "genres" : {
          "terms" : { 
              "field" : "car_name.keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Using the `keyword` type is the current best practice, `not_analyzed` `string` is a thing of the past.

Comment: I have ended up using "keyword" type and now i am getting my desired result.
I dont know why when i was using "text" field i was not able to use "field.keyword" in my aggregation.

Comment: Because you had no `keyword` sub-field in your mapping.